# unit testing a method that takes a list as an argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, mockito

I need to test a method that is taking a list as an argument. Below is the sample code:

```
public class C
{
    private int x;
    private String y;
    //getters and setters
}
public class B
{
    public void collectC(List<C> cList)
    {
        for(C c : cList)
        {
            System.out.println("int: " + c.getX() + "String: "+ c.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

So class B is simply collecting objects of class C and iteration on it using enhanced for loop.
Now, I want to test a method of class B. Below is the testing code.

```
public class BTest
{
    private List<C> cList;
    @Mock private C c;
    @InjectMocks private B b;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        cList = new ArrayList<>();
        cList.add(c);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCollectC()
    {
        Mockito.when(c.getX()).thenReturn(5);
        Mockito.when(c.getY()).thenReturn("Hello There");
        b.collectC(cList);
    }
}
```

So, this is giving me error `NullPointerException` on `System.out.println()` one line where I am invoking methods on 'c' object.
I then changed the code where I mocked a list and iterator too, so now my code is working fine. But I want to know that what is the problem with above-mentioned code and why it is failing?

Comment: You are not initializing c

Comment: oh, Silly me :) Thanks, I found the solution as mentioned by you and below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instance `c` **before** you add it to `cList` otherwise `cList` contains a null element.

The following test passes:

```
public class BTest {
    private List<C> cList;
    @Mock
    private C c;

    @InjectMocks
    private B b;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        cList = new ArrayList<>();
        cList.add(c);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCollectC() {
        Mockito.when(c.getX()).thenReturn(5);
        Mockito.when(c.getY()).thenReturn("Hello There");
        b.collectC(cList);
    }
}
```